# Crystal Reports / VS'08 - Design, Elements floating to top

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to edit some .RPT files via VS08/Crystal Reports.
Problem is, if i create new elements or delete/move existing elements, the text below (within a new section) floats up to (or above) the element i created.

How do i create elements with an absolute "top-value"?

Other than that, if there are there any design-essentials-tutorials for Crystal somewhere in the wild, a link would be nice :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the UnderlaySection Property of the Section to false solved (some of) my problem(s) and should be the solution for those stumbling on this Question..

Would still be thankful for some good tutorial links..